# How does TabLayout work?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have a `Tablayout` inside my `MainActivity` and a `Viewpager` that shows three Fragments.

When the app starts, this happens:

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 1
onResume Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 2
onResume Fragment 2
```

This happens when tapping the second tab:

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 3
onResume Fragment 3
```

Tapping the third tab:

```
onSaveInstanceState Fragment 1
```

Tapping on second tab from the third tab:

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 1
onResume Fragment 1
```

Code

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
}
```

In MainActivity

```
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(DishFragment.newInstance(1), "Кулинария");
    adapter.addFragment(DishFragment.newInstance(2), "Кондитерская");
    adapter.addFragment(DishFragment.newInstance(3), "Хлебобулочная");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

---

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 1
onResume Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 2
onResume Fragment 2

onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 3
onResume Fragment 3

onSaveInstanceState Fragment 1

onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 1
onResume Fragment 1
```

Comment: ViewPager defaults to loading the current Fragment and the adjacent Fragments. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewPager holds the adjacent Fragments in memory for quick transitions between pages. I'm thinking there's a fix for the recreated Fragments (since you're storing them in a list, add not creating them yourself more than once).

> When app started this process happens:

I'm not sure about the doubled onCreate #1, but Fragment 1 and 2 are started

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 1
onResume Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 2
onResume Fragment 2
```

> This happens when tapping at second tap:

Fragment 1 & 2 were already created, but Fragment 3 is now created

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 3
onResume Fragment 3
```

> Tapping at third tap:

The OS doesn't need to hold onto Fragment 1 anymore

```
onSaveInstanceState Fragment 1
```

> Tapping on second tap from third tap:

Fragment 1 is created / resumed

```
onCreate Fragment 1
onActivityCreated Fragment 1
onResume Fragment 1
```

Comment: Ok I see! But I found another misunderstanding. I use one fragment class for all three tabs. And it seems that items for next fragment are adding above previous items. Though I had created three different instances of the fragment. Is it in xml problem? maybe it is necessary to clear it?

Comment: You only have 3 `adapter.addFragment`. I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: The problem was solved by itself. I realized nothing
`adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(DishFragment.newInstance(1), "Кулинария");
        adapter.addFragment(DishFragment.newInstance(2), "Кондитерская");
        adapter.addFragment(DishFragment.newInstance(3), "Хлебобулочная");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);`